# Add multiple flags to windowmanager

Tags: android

I have a WindowManager params set up like this:

```
  final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, 
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT );
```

However, this is causing an error. It's fine if I remove on of the flags, but I want both. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Use a bit-wise OR for your flags to combine them bitwise: `flag1 | flag2`

```
final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT );
```